# Can I merge data and template on server side in .net?

Tags: asp.net

My project is a .net web application containing some boxes on a page with their own data. to load each of the boxes we called a web method (in a web service). we use this approach to load boxes separately(suppose a box has paging within itself and we don't want it causes loading the whole page). my question is about first loading of the page that causes all web methods call and page load slowly. I want to make html of page on server side for first loading of the page and when user open the web page for first time, we send just the made html. I mean similar  to merging json data to jtemplate but in server side. or similar what mvc architecture does. or...??? Any Idea ?

Answer (score 0):

Multiple calls to the webservice might slow down the page load. It would be better if we make a single call to the webservice and the service return a dto with data for the boxes in your page.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way would be to invoke all web methods on the server side as web service calls and send the combined html to the browser.

Better way would be to invoke actual web method implementation (i.e. calling the method code instead of web service invocation) and then combine the html.

Comment: when I load my page in some browsers that don't support java script, I can not see any data because of 
<script type = "text/javascript">            $(document).ready(function () {
                $('.btnSave').click(function () {
                    var fn = $('.fName').val();
                    }
                    $('.fName').val("");
                   
     
                    $.ajax({
                        url: "../WebServices/WS_User.asmx/SaveUser",
                        contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',... 
SaveUser is one of the web methods